# Cascading functionality in quick edit mode in Office 365

Tags: office-365, custom-list, lookup-column, cascading, quick-edit

I've sandbox solution in Office 365. I want cascading functionality of Country, State, City in SharePoint lists. I got that by using **SPServices** JavaScript but only in **NewForm** and **EditForm**.

Want this in **quick edit mode** or in **datasheet view**.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "Regions",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Country",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    CAMLQuery: "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>Active</Value></Eq>",   parentColumn: "Country",
    childColumn: "Region",
    debug: true
  });
  $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "States",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Region_x0020_Name",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    relationshipListSortColumn: "ID",
    parentColumn: "Region",
    childColumn: "State"
  });
```

I've put this script in master page.
I've refer this [link](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only source where I have found an answer, it is from 2013: http://nondeprecatingly4.rssing.com/chan-3754326/all_p127.html

It says:

> SPCascadeDropdowns does not work with the "Quick Edit" view - aka the new Datasheet view - in SharePoint 2013 as of SPServices 2013.01.